# How can I name my result to other name

Tags: mysql

I have a query like this in MYSQL DB

```
SELECT date_format( doj, '%d/%m/%Y' ) AS week ,COUNT(user_id) FROm user_tb 
WHERE doj between '2012-01-01' AND '2012-01-31' group BY WEEK(doj)

Result

week    COUNT(user_id)
06/01/2012  3
17/01/2012  2
25/01/2012  3
29/01/2012  1
```

How can I name it like this

```
week    COUNT(user_id)
week1   3
week2   2
week3   3
week4   1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the same `week()` function that you have used it in your group statement.

```
SELECT CONCAT("week", WEEK(doj)) AS week, COUNT(user_id) 
FROM user_tb 
WHERE doj between '2012-01-01' AND '2012-01-31' 
GROUP BY WEEK(doj)
```

Answer (score 3):

if you want to number the weeks starting from 1 then do:

```
SELECT concat('week', @row := @row + 1) AS week, COUNT(user_id)
from user_tb, (select @row := 0) r
WHERE doj between '2012-01-01' AND '2012-01-31' 
group BY WEEK(doj)
```

### edit

If you want the number of the week in a year then do:

```
SELECT concat('week', week(doj)) AS week, COUNT(user_id)
from user_tb, (select @row := 0) r
WHERE doj between '2012-01-01' AND '2012-01-31' 
group BY WEEK(doj)
```

Comment: One more thing. I am hitting a query similar to this one but the result is coming in reverse order for week column. It is coming like.     Week4,week3,week2,week1 So what may be the problem?

Comment: hard to tell. Maybe you are ordering in your query what messes the row count up. better ask another question.

Answer (score 1):

Search for the [`WEEK()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) at mysql site.

Answer (score -2):

I think the most efficient way is to use the rownum (rownumber) and concatenate it with "week" (Don't forget to orderby week, so that the rownumber matches with the week number).

The week function will return the number of the week in the year, and I don't think that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Yep, did not understand post at first. I've edited my answer.